# Can be the mind separated from the body?

Tags: mind, meditation-mindfulness

As e.g. if somebody harms you, you don't feel because you know that the people is only harming this body, that is just a pile of cells, and the people is incapable to harm your mind.

If yes, do have some teachings to contemplate the separation of mind and body, preferably some mindfulness technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the following sutta shows how an educated noble disciple deals with physical pain compared to an uneducated ordinary person.

The former feels the physical pain but does not lament about it, while the latter feels the physical pain and also laments about it.

> “When an uneducated ordinary person experiences painful physical
> feelings they sorrow and wail and lament, beating their breast and
> falling into confusion. They experience two feelings: physical and
> mental.
>
> It’s like a person who is struck with an arrow, only to be struck with
> a second arrow. That person experiences the feeling of two arrows.
>
> In the same way, when an uneducated ordinary person experiences
> painful physical feelings they sorrow and wail and lament, beating
> their breast and falling into confusion. They experience two feelings:
> physical and mental. ....
>
> When an educated noble disciple experiences painful physical feelings
> they don’t sorrow or wail or lament, beating their breast and falling
> into confusion. They experience one feeling: physical, not mental.
>
> It’s like a person who is struck with an arrow, but was not struck
> with a second arrow. That person would experience the feeling of one
> arrow.
>
> In the same way, when an educated noble disciple experiences painful
> physical feelings they don’t sorrow or wail or lament, beating their
> breast and falling into confusion. They experience one feeling:
> physical, not mental.
> [SN 36.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn36.6/en/sujato)

Answer (score 2):

> Can be the mind separated from the body?

While it'd take certain level of cultivation of serenity and insight to experience that on the humans plane, there're realms in the 31 planes of existence where [beings exists solely with the mind without possessing a physical body](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html).

> If yes, do have some teachings to contemplate the separation of mind and body, preferably some mindfulness technique?

Quite oftentimes, the inability to stay mindful of that truth is due to the fear of what might happen to oneself after death. It's really the fear of the unknown that makes one clings even more to what one already has. In [SN 55.27](https://suttacentral.net/sn55.27/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin), Ven. Ananda comforts the householder Anathapindika and taught him contemplation on the four aspects to remove all fright, trepidation, and fear.

Answer (score 1):

[SN 22.1](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.001.than.html), SN 36.6 and [MN 21](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.021x.than.html) are a good starting point.

Also [MN 62](https://suttacentral.net/mn62/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=pts&notes=asterisk&highlight=true&script=latin) is directly applicable, instructing to have a mind like earth, wind, fire, water & space.

> Rāhula, meditate like the earth. For when you meditate like the earth,
> pleasant and unpleasant contacts will not occupy your mind. Suppose
> they were to toss both clean and unclean things on the earth, like
> feces, urine, spit, pus, and blood. The earth isn’t horrified,
> repelled, and disgusted because of this. In the same way, meditate
> like the earth. For when you meditate like the earth, pleasant and
> unpleasant contacts will not occupy your mind.
>
> Meditate like water. For when you meditate like water, pleasant and
> unpleasant contacts will not occupy your mind. Suppose they were to
> wash both clean and unclean things in the water, like feces, urine,
> spit, pus, and blood. The water isn’t horrified, repelled, and
> disgusted because of this. In the same way, meditate like water. For
> when you meditate like water, pleasant and unpleasant contacts will
> not occupy your mind.
>
> Meditate like fire. For when you meditate like fire, pleasant and
> unpleasant contacts will not occupy your mind. Suppose a fire were to
> burn both clean and unclean things, like feces, urine, spit, pus, and
> blood. The fire isn’t horrified, repelled, and disgusted because of
> this. In the same way, meditate like fire. For when you meditate like
> fire, pleasant and unpleasant contacts will not occupy your mind.
>
> Meditate like wind. For when you meditate like wind, pleasant and
> unpleasant contacts will not occupy your mind. Suppose the wind were
> to blow on both clean and unclean things, like feces, urine, spit,
> pus, and blood. The wind isn’t horrified, repelled, and disgusted
> because of this. In the same way, meditate like the wind. For when you
> meditate like wind, pleasant and unpleasant contacts will not occupy
> your mind.
>
> Meditate like space. For when you meditate like space, pleasant and
> unpleasant contacts will not occupy your mind. Just as space is not
> established anywhere, in the same way, meditate like space. For when
> you meditate like space, pleasant and unpleasant contacts will not
> occupy your mind.